# get content of a div that contain an iframe JQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

im trying to get the content of a div generated by an editor,

the problem is that this div contain an iframe and the iframe contain a new document

here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#save").click(function() 
        {
            var txt = $("#cke_1_contents").contents();
            console.log($("#cke_1_contents").contents());
        });
});
```

and here is the content that i want to get

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 400px;"><span id="cke_89" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span><iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, content" aria-describedby="cke_89" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
    <span id="cke_89" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 938px; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, content" aria-describedby="cke_89" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        #document
        <html>....</html>
    </iframe>
<div>
```

i only get the div and the iframe without the content inside the iframe

thank you guys for help

Comment: **Always** use CKEditor API to get editor data (`CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.getData()`) because what you have in DOM is **totally different** from what is returned by CKEditor. CKEditor cleans contents up, removes temporary attributes, performs filtering and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that new document is from somewhere else than your domain name then you can't have it. To get it you need to use server side programming. But if it's from your site then yes.

```
var x=document.getElementById("myframe");
var y= x.contentDocument;
y.d.body.innerHTML; //here
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the src attribute of your iframes are empty. If you want to load an external document into an iframe, you have to set the src attribute (at least I don't know any other sensible way).

Secondly, keep in mind iframes are subject to the [same origin policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) So, if your iframe is loading content from another domain, the parent document generally won't be able to access the content of the iframe. However, there are ways around this, and I suggest  looking at the above link that covers the same origin policy in depth, as well as [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) that covers iframes in depth (including how to deal with the same origin policy when using iframes.)

If you need to load content from another domain (which I don't know because your src attributes are empty), one alternative to iframes is to get the content using the proxy method. Basically you can make a HTTP request from the server side, get the content, and add it to your page right before the page is served. This can be done rather effortlessly using something such as [curl in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor has a pretty good javascript API which you can use:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api

It can be a bit tricky to find what you need though.

See this page sto see it ina action (viewsource find the `GetContents` method):
http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7596/_samples/api.html

```
function GetContents()
{
    // Get the editor instance that you want to interact with.
    var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

    // Get editor contents
    // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData
    alert( oEditor.getData() );
}
```